# Error uploading file in ASP .NET MCV 1.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

This is my controller to upload file

Controller:

```
namespace MvcApplication5.Controllers

{
    public class DataUploadController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Index");
    }


    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Import(HttpPostedFileBase excelfile)
    {
        if (excelfile == null || excelfile.ContentLength == 0)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("empty", "some error message");
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "DataUpload");
        }
        else
        {
            if (excelfile.FileName.EndsWith(".xls") || excelfile.FileName.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
            {


                string path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/" + excelfile.FileName);

                if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                    System.IO.File.Delete(path);
                excelfile.SaveAs(path);
                return View("success");
            }
            else
            {
                return View("Index");
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

When I execute the code, I got this error:

### Server Error in '/' Application.

**'~/Content/C:\Documents and Settings\adryan\My Documents\test.xlsx' is not a valid virtual path.** 
*Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.*

Can you help me solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the file name from the file path. You may use the `Path.GetFileName` method to do that. This method returns the file name and extension of the specified path string.

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(excelfile.FileName);
string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content"), fileName);
excelFile.SaveAs(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will thrown error :

```
string path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/" + excelfile.FileName);

if (System.IO.File.Exists(path)) // <--- error here !
```

> How to solve !
>
> **excelfile.FileName** this is properties of **HttpPostedFileBase**
>   *excelfile* .. And this is a **FilePath** ! you should get only filename by use split('\') method of string and LinQ to get last index
>
> Example : **`excelfile.FileName.Split('\\').Last()`**

P.S. sorry for my english >.< !

Holp this help !